# Is it possible to call Gdk.Seat.grab() in GJS?

Tags: key-bindings, gdk, gjs

It seems when I call Gdk.Seat.grab() in GJS I get an error:

```
Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError: Gdk.Seat.grab is not a function
```

This function and class is [listed in the GJS Docs](http://devdocs.baznga.org/gdk30~3.22p/gdk.seat#method-grab), but maybe I'm calling it wrong? If I call `typeof` on `Gdk.Seat.grab` it comes back `undefined`. Is this not possible, or is there another way I can grab focus in this way?

My use case is gathering a keybinding from a user, for which I can use `Gtk.CellRendererAccel`, but I would prefer not to use a `Gtk.TreeView`. The docs say about CellRenderers that:

> These objects are used primarily by the GtkTreeView widget, though they aren’t tied to them in any specific way.

and...

> The primary use of a GtkCellRenderer is for drawing a certain graphical elements on a cairo_t.

Which implies I could use it outside of TreeView, but with no hints as to how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grab()` is a method of `Gdk.Seat`, so you need a `Gdk.Seat` object to call it on. It looks like you're calling it as a static method, `Gdk.Seat.grab()`. So, you'll need something like `Gdk.DeviceManager.get().get_default_display().get_default_seat()` or you can get a `Gdk.Seat` object from a `Gdk.Event`.

It's not clear from the described use case what you are trying to do with the grab, but there may be an easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: Ah, I should have realized that. When I can't find a good GJS example I usually fallback to finding an example in C or Vala (in this case gnome-control-center), but that's really not my forte hence the errant static method approach. My use case is user configurable keybindings for a shell extension, but the CellRendererAccel in a TreeView route turns out to be more suited for my needs. Thanks for the reply in any case.